# How do I change the candy per second rate in the JavaScript console?

Tags: cheats, candy-box

I don't exactly have a lot of patience and would like to know, how do I change the candy per second rate in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> if you are using Chrome or IE, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Firefox, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Opera, then click on Console. Type in the command and then hit enter.

```
candies.candiesPerSecond = 100;
```

(You can change 100 to what ever number you want).

If you are confused about any of this refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, `candies.setCandiesPerSecond(100);`.